# Hashicorp Vault: failed to look up namespace from the token

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, hashicorp-vault

I have installed Hashicorp Vault in the AWS EC2 server and trying to access the secret keys stored in the vault using AWS Lambda function using "AWS Authentication". But I am getting the following error.

```
{u'errors': [u'error performing token check: failed to look up namespace from the token: no namespace']}
```

I am basically doing the following

1. Installed Hashicorp Vault in EC2 server, enabled AWS authentication
2. Set up policy & role in the Vault using an AWS role
3. Created a Python-based AWS Lambda function that is generating signed AWS STS request
4. Using the signed request, successfully login to the vault server. The response is as follows.

   ```
   {
   u'lease_id':  u'',
    u'warnings':  [
       u'TTL of "768h" exceeded the effective max_ttl of "500h"; TTL value is capped accordingly'
   ],
    u'wrap_info':  None,
    u'auth':  {
       u'token_policies':  [
           u'default',
            u'examplepolicy'
       ],
        u'orphan':  True,
        u'entity_id':  u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        u'token_type':  u'service',
        u'lease_duration':  1800000,
        u'policies':  [
           u'default',
            u'examplepolicy'
       ],
        u'client_token':  u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        u'accessor':  u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        u'renewable':  True,
        u'metadata':  {
           u'auth_type':  u'iam',
            u'account_id':  u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            u'role_id':  u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       }
   },
    u'lease_duration':  0,
    u'request_id':  u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    u'data':  None,
    u'renewable':  False
   ```

   }
5. Now using the client-token from above response trying to fetch a secret key as shown below

   **secretKey = requests.get(url1,headers = {"X-Vault-Token": clienttoken})**
6. I am getting following error immediately after executing the above line.

   *{u'errors': [u'error performing token check: failed to look up namespace from the token: no namespace']}*

Comment: Did you try X-Vault-Token without the quotation marks? That was my issue in the R programming environment.

Answer (score 0):

instead of "X-Vault-Token: token" header use "Authorization: Bearer token"

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when try get/put commands in CLI hashicorp:

```
    Error making API request.

URL: GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/internal/ui/mounts/secret
Code: 500. Errors:

* error performing token check: failed to look up namespace from the token: no namespace
```

Error was that I'm used "" when set VAULT_TOKEN in env variable

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33511766)

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces feature requires Vault Enterprise Platform.